# After Upgrade From iPhone App to iPad App Images Are Gone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimage, ios-simulator

I duplicated existing iPhone app project and made it function the same with a different name. Then I upgraded copy of this project to iPad version - "two device-specific application" but I switched to iPad only app in settings. When I build in Simulator (unfortunately I do not have iPad right now to test the device), some images are either gone or if I replaced them with HD copies, they still point to low res version (though when revealed in Finder it points to HD). I am so confused.

Can someone explain how to make sure the right images are set for iPad device? I can see 2 resource folders: Resources, Resources-ipad. But all images stayed under Resources and that works fine sometimes. Images I replaced with HD are not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include them as bundle resources for the new target under Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources.